# Сортировка Listbox по длине слова в C#

Tags: c#, сортировка, listbox

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать сортировку в `Listbox` по длине слова (по возрастанию и по убыванию).
В задании так же нужно было сделать сортировку по алфавиту. Вот как я сделал:

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "Алфавиту (по убыванию)")
{
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    foreach(var item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
    list.Sort();
    list.Reverse();
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если список не большой, то достаточно использовать LINQ. Например `var sortResult = list.OrderBy(x => x.Length)` или `... list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length)`. Ну а по алфавиту еще, то используйте дальше `.ThenBy()` или что то в этом духе.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось)